# populate sqldata base table contents into dropdownlist

Tags: vb.net

What is the problem in below code. I don't know how to add sqldatabase table content into dropdownlist please help

```
Protected Sub DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList3.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SOf-22\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sales_oct_3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=s;Password=121")


    If sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        sqlcon.Close()
    End If
    sqlcon.Open()
    Dim strcommand As String

    strcommand = "select item from tgnitem"
    Dim sqlcomm As New SqlCommand(strcommand, sqlcon)
    Dim o As String = sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing many wrong things here. For things as simple as this, you should better stick to strongly typed DataSets. They'll lift a lot of burden from you. You'll not need to maintain connections, manually execute queries, traverse through results and fill them into your UI controls etc. Learn more about typed DataSets and simple binding scenarios (such as yours) and they'll give you long-term benefits.

A simple 4 step mechansim for this kind of stuff when using typed DataSets is:

1. Add a new DataSet to your project.
2. Add a new TableAdapter by right-clicking in the DataSet designer surface. Write your query and it will create a type DataTable for you. You could even drag a table using Server Explorer.
3. Add an instance of your type DataSet onto your form.
4. Set `DataSource` property of your ComboBox to this instance and DataMember to the name of your DataTable. Set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to the display and value fields of your DataTable, e.g. DisplayMember = "Name" and ValueMember = "ItemID".

Comment: None of what I have described above requires any coding (at least not by you). They are simply steps that you can easily do in your IDE.

Comment: i just want to populate only  item name from tgnitem table  which i stored in the sqlserver database ..

Answer (score 0):

see this might helpful to you

```
Public Shared Function ClientList() As DataTable
    Dim dtResult As DataTable = Nothing
    Try
        Dim objDataLayer As New ClsDataLayer()
        objDataLayer.AddParameter("@REF_USER_ID", ClsCommons.IntUserId)
        dtResult = objDataLayer.ExecuteDataTable("TR_PROC_GetClientList")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return dtResult
End Function

Public Shared Sub ClientList(ByVal cmbClientList As ComboBox)
    cmbClientList.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    Try
        Dim dtClientList As DataTable = ClsClientManager.ClientList()
        If ((Not IsNothing(dtClientList)) AndAlso dtClientList.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            Dim drClient As DataRow = dtClientList.NewRow()
            drClient(0) = -1
            drClient(1) = "< -- Select Department -- >"
            dtClientList.Rows.InsertAt(drClient, 0)
            cmbClientList.DataSource = dtClientList
            cmbClientList.DisplayMember = "CLIENT_NAME"
            cmbClientList.ValueMember = "CLIENT_ID"
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("There is no Department to load", "Talent Recruit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, from above code i didnt get anything . will you please correct the code which i posted

Comment: sameerag, where u bind your dropdown with datatable or dataset. i think in your code there is nothing which will fulfill your requirement. so i see that